# CloudPages - Link in email pre-populates form

Tags: marketing-cloud

We want to send an email to our users that asks them to sign up for a webinar. The email will be sent from MC and the form will be on a CloudPage.

Is it possible for the user to click a link in an email and have it pre-populate an email field on a CloudPage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  If the click is from an SFMC email to a CloudPage (using the [**CloudPagesURL()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/?section=cloudpagesurl) function), then you can retrieve the subscriber's email address using the `emailaddr` attribute.

**AMPScript**

```
%%[
var @emailAddr
set @emailAddr = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
]%%

<input name="email" value="%%=v(@emailAddr)=%%">
```

**Server-Side JavaScript**

```
<script runat="server">
   Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
   var emailAddr = Attribute.GetValue("emailaddr");
</script>

<input name="email" value="<ctrl:var name=emailAddr />">
```